C#.NET Print binary file to network receipt printer only by IP Address and Port (no drivers)
I have a Windows Forms .NET/C# application where I have to print binary files (it can be either PDF, PNG, BMP, PCL, or others because the original is a PDF file but I can convert it) directly to a receipt printer - EPSON TM88VII - using only the IP Address and Port.
The thing is, the solution will be spread across several locations, with spare printers and low technical support abilities, so the idea is to use spare printers and by using the same IP they should be in "plug & play" mode.
I have tried the following approaches (for PDF, PNG and PCL formats):
A) Using "Ghostscript" command line;
B) Using "Ghostscript" with rasterizer;
C) Converting the PDF to bitmap and converting to ESC/POS image;
D) Using "TcpClient", "NetworkStream" and ESC/POS commands;

So, in brief:

I have to print binary format receipts/tickets;
I can only use IP Address and Port info to print;

Can someone help me with some examples or approach ideas?
Thanks,
Bruno.
